# How does mod_pagespeed extend_cache work when LoadFromFile is used?

Tags: apache, pagespeed

The documentation of the mod_pagespeed's '[Extend Cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-cache-extend)' does not mention what happens when '[LoadFromFile](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/domains#ModPagespeedLoadFromFile)' is used.

Will Extend Cache change the URL hash anytime LoadFromFile detects a file update?

And what is the criteria used by LoadFromFile in order to detect a file update? Is it file modification time? File checksum? File inode? All of these?

Comment: Are you able to figure out how mod_pagespeed detects a change in the file

Comment: no... i'm still waiting for an answer

Comment: PageSpeed uses the origin cache time-to-live (TTL), in this case 300 seconds, to periodically re-examine the content to see if it's changed. -- This is what  I got from their doc 
https://modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-cache-extend
This means files have cache-expiry of 5 minutes (300 sec)

Comment: I made a complete rewrite of the question because I just realized that the former text didn't get to the point that I really want to understand.